# JDBC errors when running a T-SQL query that uses OPENQUERY to access a linked server

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a SQL Server query using prepared statements:

```java
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from openquery(SERVERNAME," +
                                             "'Select r.A , r.B, c.C from Y r" +
                                             "INNER JOIN X c" +
                                             "ON r.RNID = c.RNID ')" +
                                             "where  c.C in ?");

pst.setString(1, data);

ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

I get this error message:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVERNAME".

**Update**

After fixing the SQL statement to add the missing spaces

```java
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from openquery(SERVERNAME, " +
                                             "'Select r.A , r.B, c.C from Y r " +
                                             "INNER JOIN X c " +
                                             "ON r.RNID = c.RNID ') " +
                                             "where  c.C in ?");
```

I now get the error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "c.C" could not be bound

Comment: Looks like you OLEDB configuration is wrong

Comment: You are missing spaces before `INNER` and `ON`.

Comment: I added spaces before `INNER` and `ON` and I get the error: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "c.C" could not be bound.` (I updated the attribute names in the query in my post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table aliases used *within* the `OPENQUERY` function are simply not available to the query that calls it. So, this will fail with 'multi-part identifier "c.ID" could not be bound':

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(ACCDBTEST, 'SELECT c.ID, c.LastName FROM Clients c')
WHERE c.ID = 1
```

but this works

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(ACCDBTEST, 'SELECT c.ID, c.LastName FROM Clients c')
WHERE ID = 1
```

as does this

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(ACCDBTEST, 'SELECT c.ID, c.LastName FROM Clients c') AS x
WHERE x.ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you need to make simple changes in your query.
You should try as I shown below then it will work.
You use below Four part table name in a distributed query and depending on your Java backend you need to omit the database name and schema.

```
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select r.A , r.B, c.C from 
    [SERVERNAME].[databaseName].[dbo].Y r" +
                                                 "INNER JOIN [SERVERNAME].[databaseName].[dbo].X c" +
                                         "ON r.RNID = c.RNID '" +
                                         "where  c.C in ?");

    pst.setString(1, data);

    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```